# Is there a way to find out the mime type from a Google Drive link in JS or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mime-types

I want to save the urls of some google drive files into a database along with the mime type. Is there any way in JavaScript (would be best) or PHP to check the url and find out what kind of file it is? `audio/mp3`, `video/mp4` etc?

This is the syntax the file has, but there is no way of telling what kind of file it is just based on the url unfortunately: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_Tg8P0D8mAYUHlrX3NWRmwwOGc

Thanks for leads!

Comment: I think you should use `CURL` to do this job. That can handle something like this.

Comment: JavaScript or NodeJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can use cURLs `curl_getinfo` function with the `CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE` flag

```
<?php
  // the request
  $ch = curl_init($documentURL);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_exec($ch);

  // get the content type
  echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
?>
```

Your output will be along the lines of `text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`, which you could `explode` to only get the MIME-type:

```
<?php 
  $mime = explode(";", curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE));

  echo $mime[0];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! That gave me `text/html; charset=UTF-8` for an mp3 file. Is cURL built into PHP or do I need to install anything? The same when I try locally with `$ch = curl_init('file.mp3');` but it seems to give that message no matter the link I fill in. I guess the Google Drive URLs contain a redirect, is that something that can mess it up as well? Also, is this function downloading the whole file or just grabs the header?

Comment: I haven't tested it with Google Links, as I thought that they had the correct headers. With stuff like `file.mp4` though, for me at least this works fine

Comment: Does your code above work for you? Even if $documentURL is a URL to another server with http:// ? Does it load the whole file or just snitching some header-info? Thanks!

Comment: Here's a link if you would have time to try and see if it works. It should come back as audio/mp3 or audio/mpeg: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_Tg8P0D8mAYUHlrX3NWRmwwOGc

Comment: You must use these options: 

 `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` because google drive download makes a redirect

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` just in case send a http instead https.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho Genius! That's it! Thank you! One last thing. Is it actually downloading the whole file to figure this out or is it a quick thing to run? THanks

Comment: @SeaBass you can try to use `$headers = get_headers($url,1)`, the file  mime will be in $headers["Location"][1]

Comment: The only way to do not download it is sending it as a HEAD request or seting curl option `CURLOPT_NOBODY` as true. But both ways html as returned.  I tried with HEAD request, but google may block this kind of request.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho I tried CURLOPT_NOBODY but it returned text/html then for an audio file. So there is no way to do this then? It's a little long to wait for 500 MB to load to save a url with mime to the database.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho I also just realized that Google has a virus scan page for large files with a randomly generated confirmation code so I guess I can't stream a video from there anyway. Thanks for all the help!